# how to retry after delay time in rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

spring boot 2.1, rabbitmq 3.12.

I need to send data/upload file to third party server via ftp and it has to be sent successful. While sometimes the network has problem, as a consequence, the system cannot connect to ftp server or upload file.

There is only one consumer now, what I need to do is `if upload failed because of network issue, I need to wait 10 minutes then re-upload, at the mean time, this consumer can continue handle next message during this delay time(10 minutes), it cannot be blocked for this retry. And if retry failed again, then wait 10 minutes again and retry again, and so on until success`

My solution is:

there should be three queues, one for normal, one for delay queue(ttl is 10 minutes), and the third is dead letter queue. The consumer is bound to normal queue, if there is network exception in consumer, this message will be sent to delay queue, after ttl expire, this message is routed to dead letter queue, the dead letter queue consumer will upload again, if failed, this message will be sent to normal queue.

Is it ok for this solution? is there better solution?